# AWS Pen test - vulnerability scanning

Tags: amazon-web-services, penetration-testing, cloud-security, amazon-inspector

I am trying to find out if it is correct to say that - In AWS we can only perform vulnerability scanning for EC2 instances.

From my research, it seems like there can be pen tests on other AWS services, but vulnerability scanning seems to be focused on EC2? (https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/). If so, would it be safe to assume that vulnerabilities scans can be only focused on EC2 instances, but also periodic pen tests on the AWS services listed in the link above?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in seeking out pentesting which goes beyond EC2. However, the type of testing (if any) is highly dependent on which specific services you use.

It's very common that pentests do not cover all services only because they are improperly scoped. Not all AWS services will be relevant to a penetration test, but some may be critical. Here are some worthwhile misconfigurations to consider:

- S3 - Buckets have their own access controls and unique API. Without insight to bucket names and AWS expertise, a pentester cannot determine if they are misconfigured. It is fairly common for buckets to allow access to `AllUsers` which is very dangerous.
- RDS - You should make sure that databases are not publicly accessible from the internet (for obvious reasons).
- Cognito, SNS, SQS - If you are pentesting an application, you will need to take a close look at the permission and configuration of authentication and messaging services (if they are in use). Misconfigurations here can allow someone to self-enroll in applications they shouldn't.

It would be worthwhile to spend some time to evaluate each service and get an understanding of it's attack surface. Here's an [AWS pentesting guide](https://www.virtuesecurity.com/aws-penetration-testing-essential-guidance/) for reference.